# Can EF Core use MetadataType for migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there a way to get EF Core to honour `MetadataType` annotations for MaxLength etc when creating DB migrations?

I've created a person class and decorated it with `MetadataType` but the annotations aren't considered when I add a DB migration.

Comment: These are not considered at all, not only during the migration. They (EF Core team) do not find a value for implementing such functionality given the multiple alternative options they provide - entity type configuration classes (close to `MetadataType` classes , but with fluent API), `OnModelCreating`, custom model conventions (`ConfigureConventions`) etc.

Comment: But I can't share any of those with an EF Core agnostic contracts library that the my API client will consume.

Comment: That's true. But as I said, it's EF Core team decision to not support it, and there is nothing we can do about it. EF Core is using directly reflection APIs, and `MetadataType` is a component model specific concept. The only way to change that is to rewrite and replace all EF Core convention classes which are responsible for applying attributes.

Comment: I actually started looking if we can hook something into `ConfigureConventions`, but haven't time. If you are still interesting in finding solution, probably need to investigate that direction. Anyway, I don't feel right to put these comments as an answer.

Comment: @IvanStoev Your answer is correct, add it :) https://twitter.com/shayrojansky/status/1632022115829334019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not considered at all, not only during the migration. They (EF Core team) do not find a value for implementing such functionality given the multiple alternative options they provide - entity type configuration classes (close to `MetadataType` classes, but with fluent API), `OnModelCreating`, custom model conventions (`ConfigureConventions`) etc.

Actually as you have found later, there is an open issue [Conventions should honor [MetadataType] #14544](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14544) in EF Core issue tracker, but as of time of writing (EF Core 7.0) it's not considered to be addressed, which kind of proves my initial thoughts.

Meanwhile, in case you are using EF Core 7.0 or later, you can utilize the [Model building conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#model-building-conventions) and implement it yourself.

Following is a sample implementation:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class ModelConfigurationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static ModelConfigurationBuilder AddMetadaTypeAttributeSupport(this ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
        {
            configurationBuilder.Conventions.Add(sp => new MetadataTypeAttrubuteConvention());
            return configurationBuilder;
        }
    }
}

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions
{
    public class MetadataTypeAttrubuteConvention : IPropertyAddedConvention
    {
        public void ProcessPropertyAdded(IConventionPropertyBuilder propertyBuilder, IConventionContext<IConventionPropertyBuilder> context)
        {
            var property = propertyBuilder.Metadata;
            foreach (var metaProp in property.DeclaringEntityType.ClrType
                .GetCustomAttributes<MetadataTypeAttribute>(true)
                .SelectMany(metaType => metaType.MetadataClassType.GetProperties())
                .Where(metaProp => metaProp.Name == property.Name
                    && metaProp.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(property.ClrType)))
            {
                foreach (var metaAttr in metaProp.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                {
                    switch (metaAttr)
                    {
                        case RequiredAttribute dataAttr:
                            propertyBuilder.IsRequired(true, fromDataAnnotation: true);
                            break;
                        case MaxLengthAttribute dataAttr:
                            if (dataAttr.Length > 0)
                                propertyBuilder.HasMaxLength(dataAttr.Length, fromDataAnnotation: true);
                            break;
                        case PrecisionAttribute dataAttr:
                            propertyBuilder.HasPrecision(dataAttr.Precision, fromDataAnnotation: true);
                            if (dataAttr.Scale.HasValue)
                                propertyBuilder.HasScale(dataAttr.Scale, fromDataAnnotation: true);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First method is just for convenience, the actual work is inside `ProcessPropertyAdded` switch. I've added support for 3 attributes, other can be added if needed in a similar fashion.

With this code in place, all you need is to override `ConfigureConventions` in your derived `DbContext` class and include `AddMetadaTypeAttributeSupport` call, e.g.

```cs
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);
    configurationBuilder.AddMetadaTypeAttributeSupport();
}
```